# Why does this code print 248,not -8?

Tags: java

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        byte i = 31;
        System.out.println(i<<3);
    } 
}
```

Why does this code print 248,not -8?

Comment: This code prints `256` just as it should. Where are you getting `248` and `-8`?

Comment: Sorry. It's my mistake. 

The value of variable i should be 31

Comment: Then you should [edit] your question to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The output is 256 and it is ok!
You shift left it for 3.
i is 32, it means 100000 as binary so if you shift left it for 3, it will be 100000000 that means 256 as dec.

Comment: I think the data type of (i<<3) is byte,so it means 11111000 as binary ,it should be -8.  Am i miss something?

Comment: Input is a byte, but when the operation is performed, it is being converted to integer.

Comment: Byte data type is an 8-bit signed two's complement integer

Answer (score 0):

After you now edited your question:

`byte b = 31` is `0b11111`. If you now do `i << 3` this turns to `0b11111000`.

Which is `248`.

You are expecting `-8` which would be the result of `(byte) (i << 3)`. The result of a bitshift is an integer. You can convert that explicitely to a byte if you want a byte-value.

Comment: Thank you very much! I did not know the result of a bitshift is an integer

Comment: See [JLS 4.2.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.2) "The numerical operators, which result in a value of type int or long" - **all** numeric operators promote byte, short or char to int (or long, in some circumstances). Including bitshift operators.